# Unicode issues when using NLTK

Tags: python, regex, unicode, nltk

I have a text scraped from internet (I think it was a Spanish text encoded in "latin-1" and decoded to unicode when scraped). The text is something like this:

```
730\u20ac.\r\n\nropa nueva 2012 ... 5,10 muy buen estado..... 170 \u20ac\r\n\nPack 850\u20ac,
```

After that I do some replacements on the text to normalize some words (i.e. replace the € symbol (\u20ac) for "euros" using regex (r'\u20ac', r' euros')).

Here my problem seems to start... If I do not encode each string to "UTF-8" before applying the regex, the regex wont find any occurrences (despite a lot of occurrences do exist)...

Anyways, after encoding it to UTF-8, the regex (r'\u20ac', r' euros') works.

After that I tokenize and tag all the strings. When I try to use the regexparser I then get the

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

My question is, if I have already encoded it to UTF-8, how come I have a problem now? And what would be your suggestion to try to avoid it?

Is there a way to do the encoding process once and for all, like below? If so what should I do for the second part (encode/ decode it anyway)?

```
Get text -> encode/ decode it anyway... -> Work on the text without any issue
```

Thanks in advance for any help!! I am new to programming and it is killing me...

Code detail:

regex function

```
replacement_patterns = [(ur' \\u20ac', ur'  euros'),(ur' \xe2\x82\xac', r'  euros'),(ur' \b[eE]?[uU]?[rR]\b', r'  euros'), (ur' \b([0-9]+)[eE][uU]?[rR]?[oO]?[sS]?\b',ur' \1 euros')]

class RegexpReplacer(object):
    def __init__(self, patterns=replacement_patterns):
        self.patterns = [(re.compile(regex, re.IGNORECASE), repl) for (regex, repl) in patterns]

    def replace(self, text):
        s = text
        for (pattern, repl) in self.patterns:
            (s, count) = re.subn(pattern, repl, s)
        return s
```

Comment: In the text that you scraped, is the `\u20ac` chunk all literal characters or is this a Unicode string with that being an escape sequence?  Or in other words does that chunk of the text compare equal to `u'\u20ac'` or `r'\u20ac'`?

Comment: @F.J: The text is in a JSON file and I use JSON.load to open it. when I try to check with type() it says unicode... also I replace it before tokenizing, so its a long string of text (one sentence)

Comment: Try leaving your text as Unicode instead of encoding to UTF-8 and using `re.sub(ur'\u20ac', ur' euros', text)` for the normalization.

Comment: @F.J If I do that the regex does not work... it does not match the euro symbol for example... only after I do strin.encode('utf-8') I get a match...

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be misunderstanding the meaning of `r'\u20ac'`

The `r` indicates a raw string. Not a unicode string, a standard one. So using a unicode escape in a pattern only gets you a literal backslash:

```
>>> p = re.compile(r'\u20ac')
>>> p.pattern
'\\u20ac'
>>> print p.pattern
\u20ac
```

If you want to use raw strings *and* unicode escapes, you'll have to use **raw unicode** strings, indicated by `ur` instead of just `r`:

```
>>> p = re.compile(ur'\u20ac')
>>> p.pattern
u'\u20ac'
>>> print p.pattern
€
```

Comment: Its a nightmare... I have tried to replace the r' for the ur' at the beginning of the strings on the regex list. But with this it seems that the regex do not fin any match... I am using pycharm, do you think it could be something related to it? thanks for the help!!!

Comment: If you're doing regexes with python, then you need to use `ur`. Your strings should be unicode, not utf-8 encoded, just normal python unicode objects. You'll need to show more code if we're to work out what's wrong, but it's probably *not* the regex part of the code; it's some other assumption you're making about your data.

Comment: It is really weird... I have the replacement patterns and function in a file. When I just paste a string in this file (copied from the JSON file) and call the function over this string I get the results OK (using ur''). But when I iterate over a list of dictionaries from the JSON file in another file and call this same function over the same text it does not work (it seems to work when I have to replace literals, but it does not seems to understand the regex - ur'hi' would work but ur'[hH]i' wont). Could you Imagine anything that could be happening?

Comment: When I type the string on the code and pass it to the replace function, the function receives the data as a str, and the function result is ok. When I do it from the json file, the function receives a unicode and the result is bad. Wasnt it supposed to be the opposite? Work with a unicode?

Comment: just opened another question... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20228810/regex-with-unicode-and-str

Answer (score 0):

Did you use the decode & encode functions correctly?

```
from nltk import ne_chunk,pos_tag
from nltk.tokenize.punkt import PunktSentenceTokenizer
from nltk.tokenize.treebank import TreebankWordTokenizer


text = "€"
text = text.decode('utf-8')
sentences = PunktTokenizer.tokenize(text)
tokens = [TreeBankTokenizer.tokenize(sentence) for sentence in sentences]
tagged = [pos_tag(token) for token in tokens]
```

When needed, try to use:

```
print your_string.encode("utf-8")
```

I have no problems currently. The only issue is that $50, says:

> word: $ meaning: dollar word: 50 meaning: numeral, cardinal

This is correct.
And €50, says:

> word: €50 meaning: -NONE-

This is INcorrect.

With a space between the € sign and the number, it says:

> word: € meaning: noun, common, singular or mass word: 50 meaning:
>   numeral, cardinal

Which is more correct.