# Regex with unicode and str

Tags: python, regex, unicode

I have a list of regex and a replace function.

```
regex function

replacement_patterns = [(ur'\\u20ac', ur'  euros'),(ur'\xe2\x82\xac', r'  euros'),(ur'\b[eE]?[uU]?[rR]\b', r'  euros'), (ur'\b([0-9]+)[eE][uU]?[rR]?[oO]?[sS]?\b',ur' \1 euros')]

class RegexpReplacer(object):
def __init__(self, patterns=replacement_patterns):
    self.patterns = [(re.compile(regex, re.UNICODE | re.IGNORECASE), repl) for (regex, repl) in patterns]

def replace(self, text):
    s = text
    for (pattern, repl) in self.patterns:
        (s, count) = re.subn(pattern, repl, s)
    return s
```

If I write the string as bellow:

```
string='730\u20ac.\r\n\n ropa surf  ... 5,10 muy buen estado..... 170 \u20ac\r\n\nPack 850\u20ac, reparaci\u00f3n. \r\n\n'

replacer = RegexpReplacer()

texto= replacer.replace(string)
```

I get perfect results.

But if I call the function when iterating over a JSON file I have just loaded, it does not work (no error but no replacement)

What seems to happen is that when I call the function over the typed variable the function receives a STR, and when I call it from the JSON iteration it receives a unicode.

My question is why my regex is not working on the unicode, wouldnt it be supposed to?

Comment: My speculation would be that the JSON contains something else than you think it does. Perhaps `\\u20ac` (literal backslash, letter u, digits 2, 0, letters a, c) rather than a literal `\u20ac`?

Comment: `ur'\\u20ac'` this is wrong. You want `ur'\u20ac'`. Also you shouldn't have utf-8 encoded data in your unicode strings.

Comment: @beerbajay Many Thanks!!!! I think I got it now... If I use ur'' I do not need the first \ to tell the regex that it is a regular character? But if I used r'' I would need no?

Comment: The last comment is correct. `r` before string mean that string is raw. Try do like this and you can see the differense. `c = r"\n";print(c)`

Comment: @user2950162 You can't use `'\u20ac'` in a "normal" string and get the unicode character. You get a literal backslash. You never need two backslashes for unicode escapes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need something like this

```
import re
regex = re.compile("^http://.+", re.UNICODE)
```

And if you need more than one, you can do like this

```
regex = re.compile("^http://.+", re.UNICODE | re.IGNORECASE)
```

Get the example

```
>>> r = re.compile("^http://.+", re.UNICODE | re.IGNORECASE)
>>> r.match('HTTP://ыыы')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f572455d648>
```

Does it correct result?

```
>>> class RegexpReplacer(object):
...     def __init__(self, patterns=replacement_patterns):
...         self.patterns = [(re.compile(regex, re.UNICODE | re.IGNORECASE), repl) for   (regex, repl) in patterns]
...     def replace(self, text):
...         s = text
...         for (pattern, repl) in self.patterns:
...             (s, count) = re.subn(pattern, repl, s)
...         return s
... 
>>> string='730\u20ac.\r\n\n ropa surf  ... 5,10 muy buen estado..... 170 \u20ac\r\n\nPack 850\u20ac, reparaci\u00f3n. \r\n\n'
>>> replacer = RegexpReplacer()
>>> texto= replacer.replace(string)
>>> texto
u'730  euros.\r\n\n ropa surf  ... 5,10 muy buen estado..... 170   euros\r\n\nPack 850  euros, reparaci\\u00f3n. \r\n\n'
```

Comment: Thanks! But did not worked... just tried as in the updated code above, but did not change anything... it is driving me crazy...

Comment: For me it works... I get this 730  euros.

 ropa surf  ... 5,10 muy buen estado..... 170   euros

Pack 850  euros, reparaci\u00f3n.

Comment: Sorry, but what the problem you mean? I have bad understanding

Answer (score 0):

If you want Unicode replacement patterns, you need also be operating on Unicode strings.  JSON should be returning Unicode as well.

Change the following by removing `\\` and removing UTF-8 (won't see in a Unicode string).  Also you compile with IGNORE_CASE so no need for `[eE]`, etc.:

```
replacement_patterns = [(ur'\u20ac', ur'  euros'),(ur'\be?u?r\b', r'  euros'), (ur'\b([0-9]+)eu?r?o?s?\b',ur' \1 euros')]
```

Make the following a Unicode string (add `u`):

```
string = u'730\u20ac.\r\n\n ropa surf  ... 5,10 muy buen estado..... 170 \u20ac\r\n\nPack 850\u20ac, reparaci\u00f3n. \r\n\n'
```

Then it should operator on Unicode JSON as well.